# Intent filter for opening my app from Gmail's "Attach picture" / "Attach video" button

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, android-manifest, intentfilter

I would like my app to appear as an option when selecting "Attach picture" / "Attach video" from the Gmail app. (Note: I'm *not* referring to sharing or sending a picture to Gmail from my app.)

How can I register my application as a gallery/picker? I have tried the following in my manifest, but my app is not listed as one of the possible apps for selecting a picture or video from Gmail:

```
<application ...>

    <receiver android:name="MyReceiver" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <activity ...>

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" /> 
            <data android:mimeType="vnd.android.cursor.dir/image" /> 
            <data android:mimeType="vnd.android.cursor.dir/video" />
        </intent-filter>

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PICK" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.OPENABLE" />
            <data android:mimeType="image/*"/>
        </intent-filter>

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.apps.drive.DRIVE_OPEN" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.EDIT" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.INSERT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
        </intent-filter>   

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:mimeType="image/jpeg"/>
        </intent-filter>

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" /> 
            <data android:mimeType="vnd.android.cursor.dir/image" /> 
            <data android:mimeType="vnd.android.cursor.dir/video" />
        </intent-filter>

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PICK" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.OPENABLE" />
            <data android:mimeType="image/jpeg"/>
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>
</application>
```

What am I doing wrong? Do I have to register a broadcast receiver?

Answer (score 0):

Gmail is asking for an application that will send an image. That would likely translate to:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
</intent-filter>
```

For video, you could specify mime type `video/*`.

I haven't tested this, but I'm fairly certain it will do the trick.

Comment: How to code it mahn ? I mean my app is opening up but how user can pick image from over there ?